# How to transform / interpolate / rebucket columns in Pandas DataFrames based on column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

How do I transform from df_input to df_output below, using interpolation / rebucketing?

```
import pandas as pd
df_input=pd.DataFrame([ [1,2],[1,3],[0,-6]], columns=[2,5])
df_output=pd.DataFrame([ [1,0.67,1.33],[1,1,2],[0,-2,-4]], columns=[2, 3, 6])
```

df_input:

```
   2  5
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  0 -6
```

df_output:

```
   2     3     6
0  1  0.67  1.33
1  1  1.00  2.00
2  0 -2.00 -4.00
```

Eg.

To go from df_input.loc[0,5] (value = 2) to df_output.loc[0,3] (value = 0.67) and df_output.loc[0,6] (value = 1.33), the rebucketing is done based on the value of column names:

```
0.67 =  2 * (6-5) / (6-3)
1.33 =  2 * (5-3) / (6-3)
```

The column "2" is same between df_input and df_output as "2" is in both [2,5] and [2,3,6].

This is a simple example, and I also want to generalize the column names [2,5] and [2,3,6] to any given vectors of numbers.

Thank you very much.

Comment: In your example above, could you please clarify between column names (which are integers) and the actual values used in df_input (which are also integers).  It is easy to confuse the two (pun intended).

Comment: the formula you supplied is unclear. Just based on the first row in input `df`, where does the `(6 - 3)` come from in `1.33 =  2 * (5-3) / (6-3)`?